# strongly non-linear algebraic equations

Tags: equation-solving

I can not solve  the system.Can any one help me with that?  Thanks.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
f1[S_, e_, I1_, I2_, R_] := 
  -d*S - g*S*(S + e + I1 + I2 + R)/K +b*(S + R) - bcd*S*(I1 + I2);
f2[S_, e_, I1_, I2_, R_] := 
  -d*e - g*e*(S + e + I1 + I2 + R)/K + bcd*S*(I1 + I2) - scd1*e;
f3[S_, e_, I1_, I2_, R_] := 
  -d*I1 - g*I1*(S + e + I1 + I2 + R)/K + (1 - f)*scd1*e - scd2*I1;
f4[S_, e_, I1_, I2_, R_] := 
  -d*I2 - g*I2*(S + e + I1 + I2 + R)/K + f*scd1*e - acd*I2;
f5[S_, e_, I1_, I2_, R_] := 
  -d*R - g*R*(S + e + I1 + I2 + R)/K + scd2*I1;
Expand[{f1[S, e, I1, I2, R] == 0, f2[S, e, I1, I2, R] == 0, 
f3[S, e, I1, I2, R] == 0, f4[S, e, I1, I2, R] == 0, 
f5[S, e, I1, I2, R] == 0}]

(*{b R + b S - d S - bcd I1 S - bcd I2 S - (e g S)/K - (g I1 S)/K -
(g I2 S)/K - (g R S)/K - (g S^2)/K == 0,
-d e - (e^2 g)/K - (e g I1)/K - (e g I2)/K - (e g R)/K + 
bcd I1 S + bcd I2 S - (e g S)/K - e scd1 == 0,
-d I1 - (e g I1)/K - (g I1^2)/K - (g I1 I2)/K - (g I1 R)/K -
(g I1 S)/K + e scd1 - e f scd1 - I1 scd2 == 0,
-acd I2 - d I2 - (e g I2)/K - (g I1 I2)/K - (g I2^2)/K -
(g I2 R)/K - (g I2 S)/K + e f scd1 == 0,
-d R - (e g R)/K - (g I1 R)/K - (g I2 R)/K - (g R^2)/K -
(g R S)/K + I1 scd2 == 0}*)

NSolve[%, {S, e, I1, I2, R}, Reals]`
```

Comment: What error messages occurred?

Comment: `NSolve` won't work because you cant get a numerical solution when `bcd` is neither numerical nor included in the list of variables you solve.

Comment: You have 5 equations with 14 unknowns, i.e., `{acd, b, bcd, d, e, f, g, I1, I2, K, R, S, scd1, scd2}`

Comment: Hello bbgodfrey;The running of the code does not finish.

Comment: Hello Coolwater; Thank you for your reply.The running of the code does not finish by Solve,too.

Comment: Hello Bob Hanlon,Thank you for your reply.No,I have just 5 unknowns,namely;S, e, I1, I2, and  R. the others are just constants.

Comment: To use NSolve you must specify the numeric values of the constants, otherwise you have 5 equations with 14 unknowns.

Comment: Notice all five equations have `g*(S+e+I1+I2+R)/K` in common. Experiment by replacing that expression by `Q` in all five equations. Then `Solve` to see if it can find a solution for any value of `Q`,  This `Solve[Simplify[{f1[S,e,I1,I2,R]==0,f2[S,e,I1,I2,R]==0,f3[S,e,I1,I2,R]==0,f4[S,e,I1,I2,R]==0,
f5[S,e,I1,I2,R]==0},Q==g*(S+e+I1+I2+R)/K],Q]` soon returns `{}` meaning no solution. Even if it found a solution your whole system might not have a solution because of additional variables, but I think no solution for Q means no solution for your system. Please check this very carefully.

Comment: Hello Bill,Thank you for your reply.In[141]:= Solve[eq, {Q}]

Out[141]= {}

Comment: You might try using `Reduce` on that instead of `Solve`. That will take a lot longer, but sometimes `Reduce` algorithms can come up with something that `Solve` can't. If it also returns `{}` and no one can find a flaw in my thinking then that is even stronger evidence that there is no solution.

Comment: @Vedat have you tried `NMinimize[
 Total[eqns[[All, 1]]^2], {acd, b, bcd, d, e, f, g, I1, I2, K, R, S, 
  scd1, scd2}, WorkingPrecision -> 50]` ? This looks like it has a very close solution. Since the rhs of all equations are are zero, you minimize the total of squares, you'll get a solution error on the order of 10^-51 . You haven't provided the constants though, so if you do that and remove those from the NMinimize variable list, you may find it doesn't get so close.